# How do I move a group of objects and keep their new position in state?

Tags: konvajs, react-konva

I'm new to React Konva and trying to wrap my head around position.

I have a relatively simple use case; a Group containing a Rect and some Lines.  I want to be able to drag and drop the Group as a whole, and capture the new position on drag end.

I am attempting to do this using onDragEnd on the Group to set state, based on e.target.x() and e.target.y(), but this gives some behaviour that I don't understand (orange Rect in sandbox).

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/adoring-sanderson-c7sf54?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx%3A13%2C1)

How can I get the behaviour I want (blue Rect) whilst getting the new position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positions of all Konva nodes are relative to parent(s). Every node has its own `x` and `y` position.

When you are dragging a group, the position of the GROUP is changed. It means actual `x` and `y` attributes of the group instance. Even if you don't have defined `x` and `y` of the group explicitly, they still exist.

The absolute position of the rectangle on the canvas is defined by its own position and the positions of all parts. Like

`Absolute Position of Rectangle = Position of stage + position of layer + position of group + position of rectangle.`

This is your onDragEnd handler:

```js
<Group
  draggable
  onDragEnd={(e) => {
    setRectPos({
      x: e.target.x(),
      y: e.target.y(),
    });
  }}
>
```

In this code, `e.target` - is the group instance. So using its position for rectangle position doesn't make much sense and this is why you have such jumps. Because position change is applied twice: (1) by dragging and (2) by updating state.

The better approach by be this:

```js
const [rectPos, setRectPos] = useState({ x: 100, y: 100 });

<Group
  draggable
  x={rectPos.x}
  y={rectPos.y}
  onDragEnd={(e) => {
    setRectPos({
      x: e.target.x(),
      y: e.target.y(),
    });
  }}
>
  <Rect width={100} height={100} fill="orange" />
  <Line
    lineCap={"round"}
    x={50}
    y={50}
    points={[0, 0, 0, 0]}
    strokeWidth={10}
    stroke={"green"}
  />
</Group>
```